# Error destroying widget in ArcGIS JS API 3.19 (Dojo 1.11)

Tags: dojo, arcgis-js-api

I'm having problem destroying a widget with ArcGIS JS API 3.19 (Dojo 1.11)

I was previously using version 3.16 (Dojo 1.10) and the following worked fine :

```
this.myWidget.destroyRecursive();
```

Since I upgraded to Dojo 1.12 I have the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.contains is not a function
at Object.isDescendant (init.js:97)
at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:267)
at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:63)
at Object.c [as destroy] (init.js:118)
at Object.destroyRendering (init.js:353)
at Object.n (init.js:157)
at Object.destroyRendering (init.js:380)
at Object.destroy (init.js:352)
at Object.advice (init.js:119)
at Object.c [as destroy] (init.js:118)
```

Any idea what could have changed ?

Comment: A few questions:
* What widget? 
* Dojo 1.11.2 comes with the ArcGIS JS API 3.19 - how are you using Dojo 1.12 - are you pulling it in separately (and thus have 2 versions of dojo included on the page)?
*Can you provide an test/replication case in jsfilddle? You can use this as a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/f0wou740/

Comment: This is a homemade widget. I'am using Dojo that comes with the ArcGIS JS API.

Comment: you need to post some of your widget code